# Observer and image fetching does not work as expected

Tags: swift, xcode, fetch

I have a confusing behaviour of my image fetcher.
If I use following code the image from url loads properly:

```
observer = "http://d279m997dpfwgl.cloudfront.net/wp/2019/09/0920_tiger-edited-1000x837.jpg"
setImageToImageView(url: observer)

func setImageToImageView(url: String) {
        
        imageFetcher.fetchImage(from: url) { (imageData) in
               if let data = imageData {
      
                  DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     self.testingView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                  }
               } else {
                     
                   print("Error loading image");
               }
           }
       }
```

but my goal is to initiate function if observer gets info like following:

```
var observer = "" {
        didSet {
            print(observer)
            setImageToImageView(url: observer)
        }
        
    }
```

What happens is that observer receives its new value of "http://d279m997dpfwgl.cloudfront.net/wp/2019/09/0920_tiger-edited-1000x837.jpg"   from remote class (proved by printing it) but then I get an error in setImageToImageView func in following line:

```
self.testingView.image = UIImage(data: data)
```

which says

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional...
```

And I can't figure why.... I see that observer is is not empty and also the function works properly when initiated manually without observer....

Any suggestions where to look?

This is where image is fetched:

```
class ImageFetcher{
    func fetchImage(from urlString: String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ data: Data?) -> ()) {
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
            
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error fetching the image!")
                completionHandler(nil)
            } else {
                completionHandler(data)
            }
        }
            
        dataTask.resume()
    }
    
}
```

EDIT:
//printing:

```
print(UIImage(data: data)!)
```

//before:

```
self.testingView.image = (UIImage(data: data))!
```

//prints: <UIImage:0x600000a84360 anonymous {1000, 837}>
//so why the:

```
self.testingView.image = (UIImage(data: data))!
```

//still gives an error?

EDIT 2:
any UI to be printed like print(testingView) inside didset of observer gives nil even if in other parts of the code are accessible. What could be the reason?

Comment: Did you test what is nil ?  add some print to check:                   DispatchQueue.main.async { print("data", data) ; print("self.testingView.image", self.testingView.image) ; let theImage = UIImage(data: data)
                     self.testingView.image = theImage ; print("theImage", theImage)
                  }
 Waht do you get then ?

Comment: well now it seems that problem lies within self.testingView.image ..other parts get printed but this part throws an error. That view is created in main storyboard and has an outlet.. Why is it nil now but not when used as described above?:)

Comment: Can you show what are the results of all the print added in the Dispatch ? How is testingView declared ?

Comment: ```data 129614 bytes
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/Jarda/Documents/XCODE PROJECTS/R2U2/R2U2/Controller/PreviewController.swift, line 227
2020-07-24 21:40:12.073934+0200 R2U2[23207:1399719] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/Jarda/Documents/XCODE PROJECTS/R2U2/R2U2/Controller/PreviewController.swift, line 227
(lldb)

Comment: testingView is created in main storyboard, is empty and via ctrldrag has an output in the same VC where func setImageToImageView(url: String)  is declared.. and is modified nowhere else

Comment: Check the connection with IBOutlet: remove and recreate.

Comment: new outlet, whole new image view - no result. When I fire setImageToImageView(url: String) via button action with url directly - it works, when fired by didset even if other didset actions happen it says the testingView is nil..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218543/discussion-between-eljer-and-claude31).

Comment: Let's try to recap. When you use the observer, does print(observer) get printed ? What do you get printed ?  Where is the observer set ? Have you a way to post the complete demo project somewhere ? That would be easier to investigate.

Comment: is it possible that the observer is changed before viewdidload and thus firing the action before the image view is created?

Comment: If I print(testingView) inside the observers didset it gives nil as with other UI parts like print(myCollectionView) etc.....

Answer (score 0):

I was referring to other class thus all UI components happened to be empty while attempting to be modified. With notification centre problem solved.